# How to htaccess redirect 301

Tags: magento2, redirect

How to add 301 redirections for the base URL in Magento 2 via .htaccess.

http://www.example.com//?

I want to redirect to these url versions 301  to http://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on

redirect 301 /old_url new_url with full path
......
```

**You can set multiple redirects Like this**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to redirect all URLs to 301**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```